# How to redirect smtp port from 25 on one ip to 2525 on another external mail.domain.com?

Tags: nginx, smtp, port-forwarding

How to redirect smtp port from 25 on one ip to port 2525 on another external mail.domain.com?

Example: I have ip as xxx.xx.xx.xxx and listening port as 25 for smtp, now I want to forward or redirect the requests on this port to port 2525 on domain `mx1.somefreehosting.com`.

Is it possible to do it using nginx like web server or do I need to use iptables?
I want to make sure that mass mailing or spamming is taken care of.
I referred [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/112157/using-iptables-to-redirect-incoming-requests-from-port-2525-to-port-25), but was not able to comment on it as I have less reputation points.

The motive is to set email account on my Nokia Lumia which is failing to send email through smtp (may be due to port).

EDIT: (See comments with Nils)
I want to create a middle machine that simply forwards an SMTP connection to some external MTA. I am not expert so might not be able to write technically correct words.

My vps will listen on myip:25 and redirect it to external ip:2525. Don't know how feasible it is?

Comment: At the start of your question, it sounds like the client shall connect to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:25, and xxx.xx.xx.xxx shall then forward that connection to mx1.somefreehosting.com:2525. But later you say that you try to circumvent a port block on 25, which means it's the other way round. Can you clarify? Which port/IP is the client connecting to?

Comment: Also, if you want to circumvent a port-25 block, there are easier ways. Most mail providers accept mail also on ports 465 (SMTPS) and 587 (SMTP submission), try to configure those into your Lumia.

Comment: To make it clear further. Mobile connects to smtp using port 25. But mx1.freehosting.com mentions it as 2525 because of this outgoing email is blocked. I have a vps with 4 IPs, I want to open port 25 on one IP and will set subdomain as mail.mydomain.com for incoming and redirect (need help here) it to mx1.freehosting.com 2525 and then set mobile smtp as mail.mydomain.com so that it is able to send emails.

Comment: Sorry, but i still don't understand which problem you are trying to solve (might be me being dumb today). Let me guess: Do you try to circumvent a port-25-block that stops   (Mobile-->mx1.freehosting.com:25), and the latter is under your control, so now you want (Mobile-->mx1.freehosting.com:2525) and you want to know how to configure your mx1.freehosting.com how to do that? If that is so, why not just telling your MTA on mx1.freehosting.com to not only listen on 25 but also on 2525? All MTAs should have config option allowing for that.

Comment: Or, do you want instead to setup a middle machine that is simply forwarding an SMTP connection from your mobile to some external MTA that you have no control over?

Comment: The second one is what I want. A middle machine that simply forwards an SMTP connection to some external MTA. I am not expert so might not be able to write technically correct words.

Comment: My vps will listen on myip:25 and redirect it to external ip:2525. Don't know how feasible it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17074/discussion-between-rahoolm-and-nils-toedtmann).

Answer (score 2):

Postfix can be easily configured to do that, but in other mail servers I am not sure. On my experience, most of them isn't really good in flexibility.

An iptables-based solution were very simple, similar as we can read in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85932/how-can-i-redirect-outbound-traffic-to-port-80-using-iptables-locally) question as well:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d ip.of.target.mx -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination ip.of.target.mx:2525
```

This solution has the disadvantage, that it redirects *all* traffic going to this port, and not only the traffic emitted by your mx.

Maybe somebody will be coming with a direct mx-config based solution, if it exists.

---

Network providers are very glad to filter out traffic of the outgoing tcp port 25. They are doing that, because they are used mostly for spam by virused machines. If you want to have outgoing traffic to port 25, you need to use the MX of the network provider, which is not always very nicely configured (for example, you can't send mails through it to mail servers requiring authentication).

In your problems I do normally, that I set up my post on another port as well (for example, on port 24). With postfix, it is very simple.

If you want to do some like so, but with iptables, you need to redirect your *incoming* traffic, and not your outgoing. If you want to redirect the incoming tcp port 2525 to 25 internally, you can read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/513210/iptables-redirect-ports-80-443-to-8080-8181):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i -p tcp --dport 2525 -j REDIRECT --to-port 25
```

Comment: what is the significance of `-t nat` ? I will try to do this.

Comment: Your -d argument should be xxx.xx.xx.xxx!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments "*A middle machine that simply forwards an SMTP connection to some external MTA*" and "*My vps will listen on myip:25 and redirect it to external ip:2525*" i assume this is what you need to do on your SMTP forwarding middle machine:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination IP_OF_EXTERNAL_MTA:2525
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d IP_OF_EXTERNAL_MTA --dport 2525 -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The first is the port forwarding itself, the second is making sure that the connection to the external MTA is masqueraded with the source IP if your VPS, and the last is enabling IP packet forwarding in general.

I am assuming here that there are no other iptables rules already established, e.g. by some firewall framework like "firewalld" or "ufw".

But i sort of doubt that this is really what you want. Are you sure it's not the other way round, and your VPN should listen on 2525 (to prevent the port block) and the external MTA listens on 25?

Again, a simpler way to circumvent a port-25 block is to use 465/SMTPS or 587/submission